# How to reserve id before inserting record

Tags: mysql, sql, record, auto-increment, identity

I want to get a new sql record data from html form and the user could see record id in top of html form before submit it.

How to implement it so that:

1. if the user cancel html form, record id be usable for next record
2. before submit html form, the other user do not use the record id with other html form
3. I could use Auto-Increment id

In addition, I use php and mysql [on Laravel framework].

Comment: do you want your ids to not have any holes between them? You should probably not mess with that if its not absolutely nececairy, and just use auto increment keys, creating one when user enters form and deleting it if users aborts, thus creating a non-used id

Comment: What is the reason that you need the `id` the be visible before the form is submitted?

Comment: The customer insists to show id in html form.

Comment: I won't have any holes between records unless delete record by user. Also if user didn't cancel html form and close web browser, how to control?

Answer (score 0):

Because of concurrency you cannot do exactly that. For example imagine two users filling the form at the same time.

User A opened form first, was assigned id 1, user B was the second, thus 2, but then user B completes the form first, and id 1 becomes a gap.

Second scenario: user does not press 'cancel' - then id becomes stall for at least some timeout.

The simpliest way is to show users the last id in db before, so they can imply that their is going be somewhere near, and the exact autoincrement id after submit.

Comment: Thanks. The user wants to write id on paper document and user may made a mistake.